# Почему не срабатывает функция при вызове другой функции в одном контроллере?

Tags: php, yii2

Почему не срабатывает функция  isGuestCheck() при вызове другой функции actionIndex() в одном контроллере yii2?

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Posts;
use app\models\PostsSearch;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Section;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\data\Pagination;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

public function actionIndex()
{   
    $this->isGuestCheck();

    $searchModel = new PostsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $section = new Section();
    $model = $section->allSection(); 



    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
        /*'models' => $models,
         'pages' => $pages,*/
    ]);
}
public function isGuestCheck()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->goHome();
    }else{
        if(!Yii::$app->user->identity->id_role_user > 0){
           return $this->goHome(); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: А подробности? Какая функция и где не срабатывает?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Отредактировал задачу.

Comment: Значит не одно из условий внутри функции не выполнено

Comment: `$this->goHome();` - это что такое? Если данная функция не модифицирует header, то ваш код никогда работать не будет как вас нужно

Comment: Да, но если я просто вставляю тело функции if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->goHome();
    }else{
        if(!Yii::$app->user->identity->id_role_user > 0){
           return $this->goHome(); 
        }
    } в функцию actionIndex() всё работает :(

Answer (score 0):

Сначала решил что проблема в `return`, но нет, у меня все работало.

Я бы советовал вам указать `homeUrl` в конфигах web.php, например `/site/index`. Если не заработает пишите.

Comment: У меня в другом контроллере срабатывает и в этом срабатывает , если я просто вставляю тело функции if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { return $this->goHome(); }else{ if(!Yii::$app->user->identity->id_role_user > 0){ return $this->goHome(); } } в функцию actionIndex() всё работает

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Только в этом контроллере не работает вызов собственного метода или в других тоже?

Comment: Только в этом к сожалению

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Я скопировал ваш код и проверил у себя, действительно не работает, но как добавляю `return`, сразу все работает:)

Comment: можете пример показать не понимаю .

Comment: Когда добавляю `return $this->isGuestCheck();` в контроллере.

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Все, разобрался. Нужно было создать вьюшку для этого экшена. То есть создать папку `posts` и в ней вьюшку `index.php`. Видимо такая особенность Yii2. Хорошо проверьте, имеется ли у вас такое.

Comment: в функции function isGuestCheck() ???

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Создайте файл по такому пути `/views/posts/index.php`.

Comment: он имеется конечно

Comment: Без него у меня не работало.

Comment: когда я добавляю   return в public function actionIndex()
    {   
       return $this->isGuestCheck(); пустой экран

Comment: то есть да стала срабатывать если ты не активирован, НО перестаёт работать страница когда ты активирован

Comment: Верно, все что ниже метода `isGuestCheck()` работать никогда не будет, если возвращать результат этого метода.

Comment: Пустой экран потому что ваш метод вернул `null` и отображать нечего.

Comment: ))) так а как мне сделать что бы сработала $this->isGuestCheck(); Я же использую эту функцию как проверку

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Если без метода `isGuestCheck()`, `/posts/index.php` отображается корректно?

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса ) Всё отображается нормально, именно в этом то и проблема, что отображается нормально, если гость он видит страницу , а не должен.

Comment: и самое странное, что в другом контролере работает функция а здесь нет (